# What are Affine Parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, parameters, computer-vision, computer-science, equation

I am reading a Computer related paper and there is an equation (of proposed architecture) :

[image]

the author stated that γ and β are affine parameters.

What are affine parameters? I have searched online and I have found links related to Physics. I need the explanation in general terms/ Computer Science related terms.

1. Could someone please tell, what are affine parameters?
2. What does Affine Parameters have to do with computer vision/ machine learning model?

Comment: This looks more like a math question than a programming question.

Comment: Most likely affine in the sense of an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), i.e. you have a multiplicative factor γ and an additive factor β. Just jargon to make it sound "formal", pay no heed.